# Add a value in cascading arrays

Tags: php, arrays

this is only a syntax issue but I don't know how to formulate it.
I want to push the 'doc' value in the 'attach' array (same level as 'pdf' and 'pptx')
Thank you for your help !

```
<?php
$body = [
   'message'=>
       ['first' => ['bob','jim']],
       ['last' => ['bobi','jimmy']],
       ['attach' => ['pdf','pptx']]
];
//$body['message'['attach']]='doc';
print_r($body);
?>
```

Comment: The simple solution is: `$body[1]['attach'][] = 'doc';`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think need to play around with this one to understand how this works.

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan can you please help me understand how $body[1] points to $body['message']?

Comment: actually, my initial structure was malformed ( missing brackets) but it helped me to understand. correct code is :  <?php $body = ['message'=>[
['first'=>['bob','jim']],
['last'=>['bobi','jimmy']],
['attach'=>['pdf','pptx']]]] ;
//$body['message']['2'][] = 'doc';
$body['message']['2']['attach'][] = 'doc';
print_r($body);  ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$body['message']['attach'][] = 'doc';
```